# C# - New process auto will be kill when I call System.Diagnostics.Process.Start

Tags: c#, process

I call new process (C# application) from current C# App, I use:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c "+filePath;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

### I can see new process in Task Manager, but it be killed immediately

I SOLVED IT WITH CODE:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
psi.FileName = filePath;
psi.ErrorDialog = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
Process proc = Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: It probably crashed.

Comment: When I open cmd, and paste filePath, it run ok

Comment: It's not enough to go on. Where are you calling this from (webserver, console app etc)? What process are you starting? Is there any indication in the windows event logs about the crashed process?

Comment: Current process and new process are Windows Form desktop application @spender

Answer (score 1):

You can also run your application using "cmd.exe" command in `System.Diagnostic.Process`
using:

```
 System.Diagnostic.Process.Start("cmd.exe /C "+filepath);
```

this command will runs and will close cmd after running your program. 
if you want to wait for the result (maybe an error) you can use:

```
 System.Diagnostic.Process.Start("cmd.exe /K "+filepath);
```

Comment: can you send us your raw command command ? i want to see your filepath

Comment: also check this : Solution Explorer -> Right Click On project -> Add -> new Item -> Application Manifest File. and in this file comment this line: `<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />` and uncomment this Line: `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` this will give Administration privilege to your application.